# a quick, smaller Q in c++

Tags: c++

First of all, i'm just a beginner

```
int num;
cin>>num;
```

how to check if the num is digit and only 0

something to do with the regular exp? Can anybody teach me that?

Comment: Check if it's 0? `if (num == 0)`? Or do you mean make sure the user doesn't input random characters?

Comment: That title is awful I was expecting well.... more

Comment: Your use of multiple inappropriate tags will only attract down-votes to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The extraction will only succeed if the stream contains a parsable sequence of characters. The correct use is like this:

```
int num;

if (std::cin >> num)
{
    // OK, use "num". E.g. "if (num == 0)", etc.
}
else
{
    // Error, no number could be extracted
}
```

If the extraction fails, the stream remains in a *failed* state and needs to be reset (with `clear()`) before further operations on it can succeed.

(It is often better to extract entire *lines* as strings from a stream (which can never fail until you exhaust the stream) using `std::getline` and then process each line separately.)